# v-spacer in datatable grouping header

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify project. I'm using the template with a slot group.header, so far so good.

Now I want to use a `<v-spacer>` in this template. Its in a `<v-sheet>`.

When I use the `<v-spacer></v-spacer>` I expect the content on the same line. But it will be on the next line. How can I display the button after the spacing on the same line, user Vuetify's system?

**codepen**

https://codepen.io/h3ll/pen/VwWOxdJ?editors=1010

**HTML**

```html
 <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      sort-by="name"
      group-by="category"
      class="elevation-1"
      show-group-by
    >
          <template v-slot:group.header="{items, isOpen, toggle}">

            <th @click="toggle" colspan="12" class="ma-0 pa-0">
              <v-sheet>
                <v-icon class="mr-3">{{ isOpen ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}</v-icon>
                {{ items[0].category }}
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn x-small>I WANT TO BE ON THE RIGHT SIDE</v-btn>
              </v-sheet>
            </th>

    </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

**javascript**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          value: 'name',
          groupable: false,
        },
        { text: 'Category', value: 'category', align: 'right' },
        { text: 'Dairy', value: 'dairy', align: 'right' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          category: 'Ice cream',
          dairy: 'Yes',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          category: 'Ice cream',
          dairy: 'Yes',
        },
        ...
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

**Update**

I can fix it with normal css like

````html
    <template v-slot:group.header="{items, isOpen, toggle}">
            <th colspan="12">
              <v-sheet>
                <div @click="toggle" style="display: inline; width: 100vw">
                  <v-icon class="mr-3">{{ isOpen ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}</v-icon>
                  {{ items[0].folder }}
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline; float: right;">
                  <v-icon @click="deleteItem(item)">mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                </div>
              </v-sheet>
            </th>
    </template>
    ```

But I wondering why Vuetify v-spacer is not working
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-spacer` is basically just a div with the style `flex-grow: 1`. So to get this to work the parent container of the `v-spacer` needs to have `display: flex`.
In your case you can add this to `v-sheet`:

```html
<v-sheet class="d-flex">
  <!-- content -->
</v-sheet>
```

Comment: Wow great :D thx